# HybridAuth registration

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I am using [HybridAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) as my login module and I want that user have to register with *email* and *password*. How can I do that ?

In the current process, user gets mail only and then sets the password instead of doing it on the registration form.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

[User Registration Password](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword) Module will do the job for you;)

> By default, users can create accounts directly on the registration form, set their password and be immediately logged in, or they can create their account, wait for a verification e-mail, and then create their password. With this module, users are able to create their account along with their password and simply activate their account when receiving the verification email.

Comment: and i can  not do it with hybridAuth ? if i will install it i will need to disable hybridAuth?

Comment: I think they are not really affecting each other and you can have them both enabled. As far as I know hybridAuth is used for registration using third party accounts like facebook or gmail or ... but it does not add up the ability to set the password in registration phase .